# What method of password hashing should I use for CoreOS ignition file?

Tags: hash, passwords, coreos, coreos-ignition

I am attempting to install CoreOS for the first time and am currently working my way through the initial FCC file which will be transpiled into the ignition file.

The [Fedora CoreOS FCCT Specification and documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/fcct-config/) is very helpful in breaking down the syntax of the FCC yaml file, however, there is one detail I am unclear on. When building the `passwd` node, the documentation states that I can add a hashed password for a user.

My question is, is there a specific hashing method I need to use to generate this hash? I have been unable to find any information regarding being able to specify which hash function was used, and since I'm fairly new to the concept, I'm not sure if it is even necessary to do so. Can I just generate a `sha-256` hash using `mkpasswd` and paste it into the yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

> To generate a secure password hash, use the mkpasswd command: 
> `mkpasswd --method=yescrypt`

[Docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/authentication/#_using_password_authentication)